# ReactiveMongo failed to connect to ReplicaSet with error `Invalid node status Primary (expected: Unknown)`

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, alibaba-cloud-rds

We have a MongoDB Replica set from Ali Cloud. We set up the MongoDB URL as

```
mongodb://username:password@dds-xxxxx-pub.mongodb.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-xxxxx-pub.mongodb.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/admin?replicaSet=mgset-xxxxx
```

When the server starts, ReactiveMongo threw an error:

```
Invalid node status Primary for dds-2zedbafbdcdae6541787-pub.mongodb.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717 (expected: Unknown); Fallback to Unknown status
```

I looked through ReactiveMongo's source code but couldn't understand why it is expecting `unknown` status?

```
upSet.updateAll { n =>
          if (node.names.contains(n.name) && // the node itself
            n.status != node.status) {
            // invalidate node status on status conflict
            warn(s"Invalid node status ${node.status} for ${node.name} (expected: ${n.status}); Fallback to Unknown status")

            n._copy(status = NodeStatus.Unknown)
          } else n
        }
```

Comment: It's not "expecting unknown" but as indicated by the message it "Fallback to Unknown status" when the node is not properly reachable. http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/alibaba-apsaradb.html

Comment: @cchantep But I can access it from my terminal with the same link with `mongo "mongodb://username:password@dds.........."`. So that means the Mongo server has public access.

Comment: As indicated in mentioned tutorial, connection is fine (even if ApsaraDB is not a fully compatible MongoDB)

Comment: This is also happening to us when upgrade to ReactiveMongo 0.18.8 ... and this is a bug that also was present on previous version, it appeared, fixed, then apprear again ... sadly the status check is a little a mess there, if you like you may open a ticket to the ReactiveMongo guys here -> https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues

Comment: I've already open the issue here -> https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues/894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for us after ignoring the `replicaSet` option.

http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/alibaba-apsaradb.html

> Finally for ReactiveMongo connection, the replicaSet option can be removed from the URI, and the password placeholder must be replaced with the actual value.
>
> mongodb.uri = "mongodb://root:${APSARADB_PASSWORD}@dds-4e6322c0290348c49176-pub.mongodb.germany.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/${APSARADB_DBNAME}"